# How to add interactive widgets in the plot created using cufflinks, pandas and plotly in ipython notebook and create shareable Dashboard?

Tags: python-2.7, data-visualization, jupyter-notebook, plotly, dashboard

I am new to the plotly visualization.

My sample data set looks like below ( Pandas data frame)

```
df => dataframe

role    priority     year       Avg_in_Hrs      Total_in_Hrs         Avg_in_Mnths         Total_in_Mnths
A        high          2003          34.44          33                      344                24323
A        medium        2005          43.4           32                      4434               24324
C       critical       2003          34.55          78                      233                5656
C       low            2004          98.55          89                      65655               5454
E      mediun          2003          34.55          45                      24243               1312
```

**role column has more than 50 unique values.**

I am using plotly's cufflinks which bind my pandas directly to plotly. I am using ipython notebook to plot the above data. Below is my code

```
cf.go_offline()  ## Use plotly in offline mode


indexed_df = df.set_index(['role '])

indexed_df.iplot(kind='bar', title='plot',
             filename='cufflinks/categorical-bar-chart')
```

Above code is generating the plot in which on mouse hover I can see the values. However,its not that much interactive so i have tried to add drop-down menu but **all values of role column are not coming in my drop-down box.**

I am ploting it in an offline mode.
Below is the code I am using for drop down menu.

```
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl') ## set theme

buttons_1 = list()
offset = -0.5

for n, r in enumerate(list(indexed_df.index.unique())):
    n = n + 1
    buttons_1.append(dict(
        args=['xaxis.range', [offset, offset + 1]],
        label=r,
        method='relayout'  
    ))
    offset += 1

print "number of unique roles are = ",n   

buttons_1.append(dict(
    args=['xaxis.range', [-0.5, offset]],
    label='Reset',
    method='relayout'  
))

layout = dict(updatemenus=list([
        dict(
            x=-0.05,
            y=0.8,
            buttons=buttons_1,
            yanchor='bottom'
        )


    ])
)

indexed_df.iplot(kind='bar',title='plotl',
             filename='cufflinks/categorical-bar-chart',layout=layout,fill=True,
         xTitle='role')
```

How to overcome with the above issue ? Also I want to add search box to search my role value and display plot only for that value.
I want to add filters to all my columns and share the plot with others in the form of dashboard.

Thanks